# HTTP Status 404 - /FirstServlet/MyServlet

Tags: servlets, http-status-code-404

[image: Click over here to see the Result]
[image: FinalLastImage 2]

Please tell how to get the output.I am not able to get the required Results.

I want only one operation at time on clicking on Submit Button.

> tell me i want to make a simple caclculator using servlet only.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
      <title>Insert title here</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form action="MyServlet" method="get">
         <p>Select Operation:</p>
         <p>
            <select name="expression">
               <option value=1>Multiply
               <option value=2>Divide
               <option value=3>Add
               <option value=4>Subtract
            </select>
         </p>
         <p>First number:</p>
         <p><input name="firstNumber" size=10></p>
         <p>Second number:</p>
         <p><input name="secondNumber" size=10></p>
         <p><input type="submit" nvalue="submit"></p>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Myservlet.java :

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  response.setContentType("text/html"); // informing the client that which format of data/response will be send
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  int a1 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("firstNumber"));
  int a2 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("secondNumber"));
  int expr1 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("expression"));
  //Invoke the relevant method of the enterprise bean
  switch (expr1) {
   case 1:
    out.println("<h3> Multiply= </h3>" + (a1 * a2));
    break;
   case 2:
    out.println("<h3> Divide= </h3>" + (a1 / a2));
    break;
   case 3:
    out.println("<h3> Addition= </h3>" + (a1 + a2));
    break;
   case 4:
    out.println("<h3> Subtraction= </h3>" + (a1 - a2));
    break;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean ? It does not work ? What happens when you submit the form exactly ?

Comment: HTTP Status 404 - /FirstServlet/MyServlet


type Status report

message /FirstServlet/MyServlet

description The requested resource is not available.


Apache Tomcat/7.0.47

Comment: How did you register your servlet ? Did you add it to your `web.xml` ?

Comment: Never, ever, put classes in the default package. And please, write your HTML in lower-case, and enclose all the attributes in double quotes.

Comment: so now how to modify the changes and where to put the classes if not in default package?

Comment: @  JB Nizet THankyou so much its working well now.